# Newbie CSS - Two Box

Tags: css, position

I'm new to CSS, and I'm trying to put two transparent boxes in the right position one over the other (vertically align), I tried a lot of solutions but right now I'm stuck...

Comment: Do you mean that you have two of the same size boxes that you want to be on top of each other, or that you have two boxes that you'd like to be horizontally and vertically centered in a container (so, both in the middle)?

Comment: What you have tried? Share your code at http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to put them into third, container box and set its dimensions to:

- height: sum of heights of both inner boxes (+1-2 px, if any of them has a border),
- width: longer of two widths of inner boxes (+1-2 px).

Then set "float: right" for both inner boxes.

Comment: Thanks for your help, what I'm trying to do is: Put two boxes on the right side of the screen, then, one box above the box two, in this way I have two boxes, box 1 above box 2. Sorry about my english. :-)

Comment: And that is what you should get after applying my answer. To have one box over another, near right side of screen, you have to use "float: right", but put them inside third box (container). That third box of course doesn't have to have border or background so it might be (and problably: should) invisible to visitor. It's just a container to hold two inner boxes, where you want them to have.

Comment: Hi, this is what I have right now. http://jsfiddle.net/4xeCg/

Comment: I have updated your code -- http://jsfiddle.net/4xeCg/2/ -- is this something, your're looking for ("Up" up and "Box" below, both positioned right)?

Comment: Thanks to all I got the solution here the code if somebody else need it. http://jsfiddle.net/chrispaz/pnwpa/3/

Answer (score 1):

Well the the way you define your problem you leave a lot to be debated as to what your attempting to do, as there are any number of methods some better suited over others dependent upon the need. Also almost everything is transparent until otherwise defined.

For example you can have a box within a box

```
<div><div></div></div>
```

This will make the boxes appear in the same place. Grant it you need to define a hight and width to give it some dimension. But outside of that one on top of the other.

there is also for another example

```
<style>.layer{position:fixed;top:0;left:0;width:40px;height:40px;}</style>
<div class="layer" style="z-index:1;"></div>
<div class="layer" style="z-index:2;"></div>
```

this one will literally make 2 elements side by side as far as the writing of the code goes, but the inline style z-index will make one on top of the other. But again there is still more methods Im sure some I can't even think of. But in all its all dependent upon your final needs as to what will better suit you in the long run.

***EDIT***
If I understand you through your comments then you basically want my second concept originally posted, of course changed a bit so its in the right and not the left. If this is the case check out this demo on jsfiddle.net to see if this is what your looking for. http://jsfiddle.net/hEEGd/

Comment: Thanks for your help, what I'm trying to do is:

Comment: All I see is "Thanks for the hel, what I'm trying to do is:" if you submitted code to a comment and didn't enclose it in backticks ` then it may have been filtered out.

Comment: Sorry was an error. Thanks for your help, what I'm trying to do is: Put two boxes on the right side of the screen, then, one box above the box two, in this way I have two boxes, box 1 above box 2. Sorry about my english. :-)

Comment: Hi, I tried your solution but I don't know what's wrong, could you help me? http://jsfiddle.net/4xeCg/28/

Comment: Not exactly sure I understand what you mean by somethings wrong, Im viewing it on Chrome currently and both boxes appear on above the other.